# Amazon EC2 Hard Disk Storage

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm planning on moving to Amazon EC2
If I purchased the 'small instance" which has 160 GB instance storage.
Can I increase the instance storage say up to a terabyte?
Should I move to the "large instance" or is it possible to just increase the storage capacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an EBS-block to your instance. These can be up to 1 TB.  EBS volumes are off-instance storage that persists independently from the life of an instance. So when you change instances, you can take your storage with you.